# accept only number in input text box without using script

Tags: html, forms, upload, sql-injection

How to allow only number in input text box

```
<input type="text" name="price" id="input-country" required placeholder="Enter Your Price" accept="number">
```

i used the above method but its not working 
when i use only allowed type in image input i use the following method

```
<input type="file" class="custom-file-input" accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg">
```

this method works fine 
in same way how to allow only number
and how to allow only text, and protect form SQL injection

Comment: Btw, if you really want to protect from SQL injection, I recommend this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Click this for checking how to enter numeric text only in HTML](http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml)

If you are using `HTML5` then use `<input type="number">`

If you realy wish to get rid of SQL injection [Use this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript like:

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57">
```

The above code only accepts numbers.

If you want to use decimal number then you can use like:

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 46 && event.charCode <= 57">
```

Try this code, maybe it will help.